# Ethereum Wallet not starting node

Tags: wallets

Ive installed Ethereum Wallet 8.10, and when I try to sign in it says to wait until my node has fully started. it says downloading blocks (5 peers) and 139,782 of 3,944,815. Does this usually take a long time? Did I miss a step?